# Equivalent text editor to MS-DOS Editor

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

While I respect the power and flexibility of emacs, vim, etc, I miss [MS-DOS Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_Editor).

It's very simple to use, has a nice color display and a menu system which, if I remember correctly, you could navigate with the arrow keys. It's very straightforward and user friendly.

Is there an equivalent in Ubuntu?

Title screen:

[image]

Find and replace:[image]

Comment: I guess you know about nano? It's close but not quite as ... colorful. There are syntax colors though. You can at least see what actions are possible.

Comment: Ahhh... I miss those old DOS-character menus and dialogs. With shadows, even! I learned C with Borland, and one of the first thing I did was write libraries to build UIs like that.  I can't see using something like this today, though, for anything other than nostalgia. To that end, you could probably configure Vim to look a lot like that. Or it could be a fun project to recreate it yourself. :)

Answer (score 34):

## [Nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/) (Installed by default)

> nano is a GPL Licensed curses-based text editor for Unix and Unix-like systems.

[image: Nano Screenshot]

Comment: In the footer, you see shortcuts with their corresponding actions. `^X` means "Ctrl + X". Press `F1` to get a help page. You might be interested in customizing `nano` (e.g. wordwrap, smooth scrolling), run the command `man nanorc` to get a list of options.

Answer (score 33):

## MCEdit

You can try `mcedit`, it looks a lot like MS-DOS Edit.
I dont remember if it comes with ubuntu, probably you have to install `mc` [image: install] (midnight commander)

Screenshot:
[image: mcedit]

Comment: Not to mention that you get to enjoy the good ol' days of Norton Commander as an added bonus if you just run `mc`.

Answer (score 29):

Another choice, available in the repos, powerful and more close to Borland's compilers editor, is the editor `fte`.

Available in the following versions:

- xwindows, command `xfte`, package `fte-xwindow`;
- terminal, command `sfte`, package `fte-terminal`;
- console,  command `vfte`, package `fte-console`.

A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This one looks the closest to the MS-DOS editor. The menus in particular make it more like the MS-DOS editor than any of the other options presented.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get install fp-ide
```

and run:

```
fp file.txt
```

100% like "edit" in MsDos. It is IDE fo freepascal but it can edit text files.

- multiple windows
- save last session
- gcalctour
- ascii table
- grep
- undo redo
- find and replace
- Console Mouse Support (install gpm) ...and more

Is part in free pascal ..it can be run without download full free pascal

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's cool! And It's `fp file.txt` to call up the editor, not `fc`! I almost gave up since `fc` gave me the 'not found' error.

Comment: Obviously this is the closest to EDIT.COM (MS-DOS Editor). It looks like Turbo Pascal.